# Python, pandas dataframe, groupby column and known in advance values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, apply

Consider this example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     [
...         ['X', 'R', 1],
...         ['X', 'G', 2],
...         ['X', 'R', 1],
...         ['X', 'B', 3],
...         ['X', 'R', 2],
...         ['X', 'B', 2],
...         ['X', 'G', 1],
...     ],
...     columns=['client', 'status', 'cnt']
... )
>>> df
  client status  cnt
0      X      R    1
1      X      G    2
2      X      R    1
3      X      B    3
4      X      R    2
5      X      B    2
6      X      G    1
>>>
>>> df_gb = df.groupby(['client', 'status']).cnt.sum().unstack()
>>> df_gb
status  B  G  R
client
X       5  3  4
>>>
>>> def color(row):
...     if 'R' in row:
...         red = row['R']
...     else:
...         red = 0
...     if 'B' in row:
...         blue = row['B']
...     else:
...         blue = 0
...     if 'G' in row:
...         green = row['G']
...     else:
...         green = 0
...     if red > 0:
...         return 'red'
...     elif blue > 0 and (red + green) == 0:
...         return 'blue'
...     elif green > 0 and (red + blue) == 0:
...         return 'green'
...     else:
...         return 'orange'
...
>>> df_gb.apply(color, axis=1)
client
X    red
dtype: object
>>>
```

What this code does, is groupby in order to get counts of each category (red, green, blue).
Than apply is used in order to implement logic for determining color of the each client (in this case there is only one).

The problem here is in fact that groupby object can conain any combiantion of RGB values.
For example, I can have R and G column but not B, or I could have just R column, or I will not have any of the RGB coluimns.

Because of that fact, int the apply function, I had to introduce if statements for each column in order to have counts for each color no matter if its value is in the groupby object or not.

Do I have any other option to enforce the logic from color function, using something else instead of apply in such (ugly) way?

For example, in this case I know in advance that I need counts for exactly three categories - R, G and B. I need something like group by column and these three values.

Can I group dataframe by these three categories (series, dict, function?) and always get zero or a sum for all three categories no matter whether they exist in group or not?

Comment: Can you give example of the case where your grouped dataframe does not contains any `RGB` values or simply doesn't contain any one of the values?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#changed data for more combinations

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['W', 'R', 1],
        ['X', 'G', 2],
        ['Y', 'R', 1],
        ['Y', 'B', 3],
        ['Z', 'R', 2],
        ['Z', 'B', 2],
        ['Z', 'G', 1],
     ],
     columns=['client', 'status', 'cnt']
)
print (df)
  client status  cnt
0      W      R    1
1      X      G    2
2      Y      R    1
3      Y      B    3
4      Z      R    2
5      Z      B    2
6      Z      G    1
```

Then is added `fill_value=0` parameter for replace non matched values (missing values) to `0`:

```
df_gb = df.groupby(['client', 'status']).cnt.sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
#alternative
df_gb = df.pivot_table(index='client', 
                       columns='status', 
                       values='cnt', 
                       aggfunc='sum', 
                       fill_value=0)
print (df_gb)
status  B  G  R
client         
W       0  0  1
X       0  2  0
Y       3  0  1
Z       2  1  2
```

Instead function is created helper DataFrame with all combinations of 0,1 and added new column for `output`:

```
from  itertools import product

df1 = pd.DataFrame(product([0,1], repeat=3), columns=['R','G','B'])
#change colors like need
df1['output'] = ['no','blue','green','color2','red','red1','red2','all']
print (df1)
   R  G  B  output
0  0  0  0      no
1  0  0  1    blue
2  0  1  0   green
3  0  1  1  color2
4  1  0  0     red
5  1  0  1    red1
6  1  1  0    red2
7  1  1  1     all
```

Then for replace values above `1` to `1` is used [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
print (df_gb.clip(upper=1))
   B  G  R output
0  0  0  1    red
1  0  1  0  green
2  1  0  1   red1
3  1  1  1    all
```

And last is used [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for new output column, there is no `on` parameter, so joined by intersection of columns in both DataFrames, here `R,G,B`:

```
df2 = df_gb.clip(upper=1).merge(df1)
print (df2)
   B  G  R output
0  0  0  1    red
1  0  1  0  green
2  1  0  1   red1
3  1  1  1    all
```

Comment: your solution didn't work (or I have missed something) in case that initial dataframe is 
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['W', 'R', 1],
        ['X', 'G', 2]
     ],
     columns=['client', 'status', 'cnt']
)

but what works in this case is:
df.groupby(['client', 'status']).cnt.sum().unstack().reindex(columns=['R', 'G', 'B'])

Key ingredient here is reindex(columns=['R', 'G', 'B']).
If I know columns in advance this will ensure that they will be always present in the dataframe.